# AWS S3 QueryString Authorization

Tags: php, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, authorization

## Background

I am trying to create a signed url to fetch a resource from AWS S3. There are [several examples in aws s3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationExamples) , and as a first step I am trying to replicate the last example on that page.

## My code is :

```
$access_key = "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE";
$secret_key = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";
$string_to_sign = "GET\n\n\n1175139620\n/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg";
$encode = hash_hmac('sha1', utf8_encode($string_to_sign) , $secret_key) ;
echo base64_encode($encode). "\r\n" ;
```

The above code outputs

```
MzY5ODAyOGU3MGYzYWNjZjk2MTczYTA0MzU3OWE5MzQzNTJjNGE3Zg==
```

According to the example, the result should be

```
NpgCjnDzrM%2BWFzoENXmpNDUsSn8%3D&
```

I do understand that the result needs to be url encoded , but I think I am still far off. Can I get some help please ?

Answer (score 6):

### I found the solution

`$encode = hash_hmac('sha1', utf8_encode($string_to_sign),  $secret_key);`

is replaced by

`$encode = hash_hmac('sha1', utf8_encode($string_to_sign),  $secret_key, true );`

Final script to simulate the example is :

```
$access_key = "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE";
$secret_key = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";
$string_to_sign = "GET\n\n\n1175139620\n/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg";
$encode = hash_hmac('sha1', utf8_encode($string_to_sign),  $secret_key , true ) ;
echo urlencode(base64_encode($encode)) . "\r\n"  ;
```

Comment: If someone is looking for SDK solution, take a look into [Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html).